# System Disk space less than what the Disk viewer shows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap

I installed Ubuntu by shrinking my Windows partition in gParted to get 140GB of free space, then chose the "something else" option in the installer, gave my Ubuntu partition 128GB, and the remaining 12GB to swap. The installer showed my Ubuntu partition as having 127.7GB and my swap as 12.3GB for some odd reason, but I just went ahead with it.

The install went well, but the disk space in System Details shows 125.6GB, and the Disk viewer shows 128GB for Ubuntu and 12GB for swap. Is that missing 2.4GB simply what was taken by the OS files?

Also, is it possible to verify that my swap space is set to 12GB and not 12.3GB?

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a subtle difference between a GB and a GiB.

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, gParted used GiB, so I had to convert GBs to GiBs to get an actual 140GB of free space. The installer just used GBs I believe.

Comment: Ah, it might be the reserved space.